# Import *.svg file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, svg, format

I installed the new version of QGIS 2.16 and I want to import an image (SVG file) as symbol for my point, but the setting style supports only xml format in import. Before, with an older version of QGIS, importing SVG files was possible.

How can I do this in the new version?

---

[image]

if i check svg symbol, I don't have the windows svg groups and images, my screen shot it's different

Answer (score 2):

You can add the folder containing your svg files in `Settings > Options > System` in `SVG paths`.

To select the svg file, right click on your layer, go to `Properties > Style` and change the symbol layer type to `SVG Marker` (Default is `Simple marker`) like shown in the screen shot. You should then be able to select your symbol.

[image]

---

Edit: In newer versions of QGis, you have to scroll down in the preferences menu to be able to see the SVG groups and images.

Comment: If  I check on svg marker, I don't see the box svg groups and images the screen shot is differt. Look